# Github Windows: New branch created from command line not showing up on github.com

Tags: windows, github, branch, push

I created 2 new branches using the command line, and when I use the command 'git branch' I can see all of my branches in the window, but when I used the command 'git push' I get a message that says, "nothing to commit, working directory clean' and so I'm not seeing my new branches on github.com.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!
Robin

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Have you tried `git push origin my_new_branch`?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. I'm taking a really great beginning github tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFYyTZwMyAg, and somehow, I missed that step!

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The below command will work:

git push origin devbranch

Answer (score 0):

After running the above command git push origin dev I got this error "remote: Repository not found."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I ran git push from within a submodule. I created a branch, but couldn't see it in the remote.

Make sure you are in the project root folder, or at least not inside a submodule when you run git push origin new_branch.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error in which i created and published a branch on one computer. But on another It wouldnt add the branch automatically (even though the git server had the new branch). I simply did a pull from shell rather than using the app's sync function. once I did the `git pull` then it added the new branch and was able to be selected from the gui.

I assume this is a bug

Comment: Please be specific on which app you are talking about. This may be a bug with the app you're talking about but this is unrelated to the original question.